# Adding all digits for a positive integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to add all the digits of a positive integer. When I test out the number 434, the result was 4, instead of 11.

Here is what I have, I don't understand why is my code not going through all the digits of the number. How to correct it?

```
def digit_sum(x):
  n=0
  if x>0:
    #get the end digit of the number,add to n
      n+=x%10
      #remove the end digit of the number
      x=x//10
  return n
```

Comment: It should be while x>0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two main constructs of procedural programming are:

1. Choosing among different things *once*. (Selection)
2. Doing things *more* that once. (Iteration)

An `if` statement is a selection statement. Since you want to add up *all* the digits in the number, your use of `if` is inappropriate. In other words, using a selection statement will only give you the sum of the first digit you process (the final `4` in `434`).

Instead you should use an iteration statement like `while`:

```
def digit_sum(number):
  sumOfDigits = 0
  while number > 0:
      sumOfDigits += number % 10
      number = number // 10
  return sumOfDigits
```

You'll notice I've used more descriptive variable names. That's a good habit to get into because it self-documents your code.

---

You can also look into more *Pythonic* ways of doing this, such as:

```
def digit_sum(number):
    return sum([int(digit) for digit in str(number)])
```

Whether that can be considered *better* is open for debate but it's a well-known way of writing Python succinctly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `if` statement, use a `while` statement:

```
def digit_sum(x):
  n=0
  while x>0:
    #get the end digit of the number,add to n
      n+=x%10
      #remove the end digit of the number
      x=x//10
  return n
```

The if will evaluate only once and return value on n after one iteration, while runs the code in a loop till all digits are added to the sum.

This will give:

```
In [2]: digit_sum(10)
Out[2]: 1

In [3]: digit_sum(434)
Out[3]: 11
```

Alternatively, a one liner:

```
In [4]: digit_sum = lambda x: sum(map(int, str(x)))

In [5]: digit_sum(434)
Out[5]: 11
```

---

If instead of 11, you want to sum those digits again as well to get a single digit, just recurse:

```
In [6]: def digit_sum(x):
   ...:   n=0
   ...:   while x>0:
   ...:     #get the end digit of the number,add to n
   ...:       n+=x%10
   ...:       #remove the end digit of the number
   ...:       x=x//10
   ...:   return n if n < 10 else digit_sum(n)
   ...: 

In [7]: digit_sum(434)
Out[7]: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not a function, it helped me:

```
digits = "12345678901234567890"
digit_sum = sum(map(int, digits))
print("The equation is: ", '+'.join(digits))
print("The sum is:", digit_sum)
```

(This prints:

```
The equation is:  1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+0
The sum is: 90
```

)

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the number to a string, then parse and sum each digit:

```
def digit_sum(x):
    numList = [int(d) for d in str(x)]
    return sum(numList)
```

Comment: You need a test for positive integers, e.g. `[int(d) for d in str(x) if x > 0]`

Comment: @pylang That'll only check for positive numbers, you'll also need a `and x%1 == 0` or `str(int(x))` or similar to ensure it's an integer

Comment: @NickA that's true if a float string or non-numeric is a given.  It wouldn't hurt to test for integers.